# Ending a sentence with "as well"

Tags: american-english, informal-language, spoken-english

I know the "as well" at the end of a sentence is the same as "too" but I'm wondering if it sounds natural enough in informal conversations (in American English).

Comment: I used to have this problem as well ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to worry about with using "as well" itself as part of a normal mixture of wordings.  Completely normal as long as it doesn't somehow draw attention to itself, by being used every time it could or continuously with wordings from a sort of "British-English affectedness".

For instance, if you combine it with "Ah yes,"

- "Ah yes, I have encountered the phenomenon as well."

In American English this would generally only be done for fun, and is fine in an informal setting.  In a formal setting, you might be *more likely to avoid it* to keep from sounding "weird".  Whenever it were used, it would generally stop after a moment of "playing the character who talks like that".

If you kept it going too long and didn't drop it--and went on to *"Might you pass the potato salad, perchance?"*--it would be over-the-top.  :-)  But it's fine to do, with awareness.  Playful use of variation in language is what keeps us from getting bored using the same sentences all the time.